# jqgrid multiselect doesn't show the selected rows in pagination

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid. I do the following steps:

1. select 2 rows and click next page
2. From the next page I select 2 rows
3. When I back to the first page, my selected rows aren't show up any more
4. When I go back to the next page again, my selected rows are not show up, too

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov Thank you for the response. I used: jqGrid  4.5.2

Comment: This feature is not available in this version. It is available in commercial Guriddo jqGrid - the option that do this is **preserveSelection**